# Converting characters to their python escape sequences

Tags: python, escaping

Is it possible to take a string, and convert **all** the characters into their Python escape sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supports full escaping of both `str` and `unicode` (now produces the shortest escape sequence):

```
def escape(s):
    ch = (ord(c) for c in s)
    return ''.join(('\\x%02x' % c) if c <= 255 else ('\\u%04x' % c) for c in ch)

for text in (u'\u2018\u2019hello there\u201c\u201d', 'hello there'):
    esc = escape(text)
    print esc

    # code below is to verify by round-tripping
    import ast
    assert text == ast.literal_eval('u"' + esc + '"')
```

Output:

```
\u2018\u2019\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65\u201c\u201d
\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65
```

Comment: What about strings containing a mix of unicode characters and standard characters?

Comment: @Acorn the `unicode \uABCD` escape sequence will cover the full range of characters. Did you want the shortest possible escape sequence?

Comment: @Acorn I updated it to produce the shortest sequence it can, so chars whose `ord(c) <= 255` will be encoded as `\xAB` form, even in unicode string.

Comment: @samplebias: Even better! (you forgot to change the output though)

Answer (score 5):

`repr()` escapes all the characters that need to be escaped

```
repr(string)
```

There are other methods in the standard library for the likes of escaping URIs and so on

Comment: Is there a way to escape all characters?

Comment: @Acorn, you could do something like this `print "".join("\\x"+c.encode('hex') for c in "ABCDE")`